# Increasing computation speed in Fortran

Tags: performance, optimization, fortran, gfortran

I have some basic psuedo code as follows,

```
PROGRAM PSUEDOEXAMPLE
IMPLICIT NONE
!Define all types

!Load some data into arrays: Array_I, Array_J


!Do Loops
do i = 1,10
   xi = Array_I(i,1)
   yi = Array_I(i,2)
   zi = Array_I(i,3)

   do j =1,10
      xj = Array_J(j,1)
      yj = Array_J(j,2)
      zj = Array_J(j,3)

      separation = ((xi - xj)**2 + (yi-yj)**2 +(zi-zj)**2)**0.5

   enddo

enddo



END PROGRAM PSUEDOEXAMPLE
```

I can time the time it takes for a single `i`-step to be ~0.3 seconds. What are the best ways to reduce this time? I can see potentially removing the square root would be effective. I am using gfortran as my compiler.

Comment: You might want to give some information about which compiler flags you're using, and possibly some information on the compiler version and your system (this will help people to be able to compare the time on your system and theirs). You may wish to try using the `sqrt` function rather than `**0.5`, being more specific can help the compiler (although may not have much effect here. I think you really also need to give some more details about *how* you're timing this -- there are good ways and bad ways! Finally, can you show the actual code for `!Define all types` instead of this comment?

Comment: If you care about performance we need the details, not pseudocode. Exact code, compiler version, compiler flags, the way you are timing it, your hardware. In performance details matter.

Comment: *I can see potentially removing the square root would be effective*  Well, removing all the code would be effective at speeding the program up, but it might not be a productive step to take ...  What are you really trying to do ?

Comment: OpenMP may be an option if you have a multi-core CPU http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/OpenMP

Comment: As this problem is symmetric, you can speed up your computation by doing only half the computations (use `do j=i+1,10` for the inner loop).

Comment: How and where is the `separation` variable used? Is it actually an array?

Comment: @haraldkl The set of `J` points are not (necessarily) the same as the set of `I` points. If they followed your advice, no separations would be found from point `I(10)`.

Comment: @SteveES, ah, sorry you are right. I missed the difference between I and J. OK, in this case it is not symmetric. There is little we can say, see the other comments.